# Lubuntu: Switching tty causes lightdm to stop

Tags: lubuntu, lightdm, 16.10, tty

On Lubuntu 16.10, running lightdm with ratpoison, if I switch to a tty in the range 8 to 12 (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F8</kbd> etc.) then lightdm stops and I cannot switch back to the default tty7 or to any text-only tty (1 to 6). I was able to recover without a reboot by running `sudo service lightdm restart` via ssh.

Below is what appeared in the syslog immediately after this event. There is a suspicious assertion error from lightdm, a bug?

Why is this happening and how can I stop it?

```
Jan 16 23:25:18 DanPC systemd[1]: Stopping Light Display Manager...
Jan 16 23:25:18 DanPC org.a11y.atspi.Registry[1731]: XIO:  fatal IO error 11 (Resource temporarily unavailable) on X server ":0"
Jan 16 23:25:18 DanPC org.a11y.atspi.Registry[1731]:       after 27717 requests (27717 known processed) with 0 events remaining.
Jan 16 23:25:18 DanPC systemd[1]: Stopped Light Display Manager.
Jan 16 23:25:18 DanPC systemd[1]: Starting Detect the available GPUs and deal with any system changes...
Jan 16 23:25:18 DanPC gpu-manager[28308]: /etc/modprobe.d is not a file
Jan 16 23:25:18 DanPC gpu-manager[28308]: message repeated 4 times: [ /etc/modprobe.d is not a file]
Jan 16 23:25:18 DanPC gpu-manager[28308]: Error: can't open /lib/modules/4.8.0-34-generic/updates/dkms
Jan 16 23:25:18 DanPC gpu-manager[28308]: Error: can't open /lib/modules/4.8.0-34-generic/updates/dkms
Jan 16 23:25:18 DanPC gpu-manager[28308]: update-alternatives: error: no alternatives for x86_64-linux-gnu_gfxcore_conf
Jan 16 23:25:18 DanPC systemd[1]: Started Detect the available GPUs and deal with any system changes.
Jan 16 23:25:18 DanPC systemd[1]: Starting Light Display Manager...
Jan 16 23:25:18 DanPC kernel: [113240.772516] show_signal_msg: 27 callbacks suppressed
Jan 16 23:25:18 DanPC kernel: [113240.772520] chrome[28306]: segfault at 968 ip 00007f3e3a8fd613 sp 00007ffea3486a90 error 4 in libX11.so.6.3.0[7f3e3a8d5000+135000]
Jan 16 23:25:18 DanPC systemd[1]: Started Light Display Manager.
Jan 16 23:25:19 DanPC lightdm[28334]: g_object_unref: assertion 'G_IS_OBJECT (object)' failed
Jan 16 23:25:19 DanPC systemd[1]: Created slice User Slice of lightdm.
Jan 16 23:25:19 DanPC systemd[1]: Starting User Manager for UID 109...
Jan 16 23:25:19 DanPC systemd[1]: Started Session c9 of user lightdm.
Jan 16 23:25:19 DanPC systemd[28357]: Starting D-Bus User Message Bus Socket.
Jan 16 23:25:19 DanPC systemd[28357]: Reached target Timers.
Jan 16 23:25:19 DanPC systemd[28357]: Reached target Paths.
Jan 16 23:25:19 DanPC systemd[28357]: Listening on D-Bus User Message Bus Socket.
Jan 16 23:25:19 DanPC systemd[28357]: Reached target Sockets.
Jan 16 23:25:19 DanPC systemd[28357]: Reached target Basic System.
Jan 16 23:25:19 DanPC systemd[28357]: Reached target Default.
Jan 16 23:25:19 DanPC systemd[28357]: Startup finished in 24ms.
Jan 16 23:25:19 DanPC systemd[1]: Started User Manager for UID 109.
Jan 16 23:25:19 DanPC org.a11y.atspi.Registry[28383]: SpiRegistry daemon is running with well-known name - org.a11y.atspi.Registry
Jan 16 23:25:19 DanPC spacenavd[976]: No protocol specified
Jan 16 23:25:19 DanPC spacenavd[976]: failed to open X11 display ":0.0"
Jan 16 23:25:20 DanPC spacenavd[976]: No protocol specified
Jan 16 23:25:20 DanPC spacenavd[976]: failed to open X11 display ":0.0"
Jan 16 23:25:21 DanPC spacenavd[976]: No protocol specified
Jan 16 23:25:21 DanPC spacenavd[976]: failed to open X11 display ":0.0"
Jan 16 23:25:22 DanPC spacenavd[976]: No protocol specified
Jan 16 23:25:22 DanPC spacenavd[976]: failed to open X11 display ":0.0"
Jan 16 23:25:23 DanPC org.gtk.vfs.Daemon[28367]: A connection to the bus can't be made
Jan 16 23:25:23 DanPC lightdm[28334]: g_object_unref: assertion 'G_IS_OBJECT (object)' failed
Jan 16 23:25:23 DanPC systemd[1]: Started Session c10 of user daniel.
Jan 16 23:25:23 DanPC systemd[1]: Stopping User Manager for UID 109...
```